# Facebook graph api create unpublished post

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use the graph API (in javascript) to create an unpublished page post. XXXX is a valid page id.

```
var pagefeed ="/" + XXXX + "/feed";
FB.api(pagefeed, "POST", {"message": "hello", "published" : false},  function     (response) {  
// handle response
});
```

This gives me an error:
{"error":{"message":"(#200) Unpublished posts must be posted to a page as the page itself.","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}

I tried adding the "name" and "id" of the page as parameters of "from" field, but that did not help. What do I need to pass for this call to work?

Answer (score 3):

You've probably figured this out by now, but for anyone else having this problem: the correct param name is "is_published", not just "published".

Comment: Thank you @Pavel Pichrt. Even though this API has now been deprecated it seems FB has not fixed this typo in their SDK examples, that helped!